# .NET Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 138:        
>   Line 139:         Line 140:
>    Line 141:         Line 142:
>
> Source File: C:\Cerquit\CAS\BJSDLeasing\Publish\web.config    Line:
>   140
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491

Comment: Looks like you should check C:\Cerquit\CAS\BJSDLeasing\Publish\web.config line 140

Comment: Did you check you references. it looks like its missing reference for `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: I just downloaded the MVC drivers. That's what I forgot. Anyways, thanks for the help